# Django form error - cannot validate as input field is required

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms

i'm trying to pass html5 date input (start and end dates) into django forms, the main goal being to query for orders according to the start/end dates specified by the user on the front-end. the user indicates the start and ends dates on the front-end, which are then passed into my django model and into an AJAX call.

[image]

my current error is this: i can't append the start/end date to my form or enter the `if form.is_valid()` portion of my code. when i `print(form.error)`, i get: `<ul class="errorlist"><li>start_time<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>end_time<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>`

i don't understand why i'm getting this error - a POST request was made and managed to retrieve my start and end dates: `<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'FDRiqkYiP6j8yOAMLfb0sMe8wC8Z0K57'], u'start_date': [u'2018-12-17'], u'end_date': [u'2018-12-20']}>` - the specified fields clearly aren't empty.

is it something wrong with my `forms.py`? would really appreciate some assistance. thanks!

**views.py** method

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.contrib import messages
from django.utils import simplejson # JsonResponse
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token
from django.db.models import Count
from django.views.generic import View

from .forms import DateInput, DateForm
from .models import Member, Driver, Order, Distance

from collections import OrderedDict

def date_input(request):    
    
    if request.method == "POST": 
        print(request.POST）# prints: <QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'FDRiqkYiP6j8yOAMLfb0sMe8wC8Z0K57'], u'start_date': [u'2018-12-17'], u'end_date': [u'2018-12-20']}>

        start_date = request.POST.get("start_date", None) # type unicode
        end_date = request.POST.get("end_date", None)
        
        form = DateForm(request.POST or None)
    
        print(form.errors) # prints: <ul class="errorlist"><li>start_time<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>end_time<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>

        if form.is_valid():
            start_date = form.cleaned_data['start_date']
            end_date = form.cleaned_data['end_date']

            form.save()
            form = DateForm()
            
            print("----")
            print(form)
            print("form validated")

        else:
            print("form is not valid")    
    else:
        form = DateForm()
        print("form is not valid")
        # print(form)

    return render(request, 'date_input.html', {
        "form": form
    })
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms 

class DateInput(forms.DateInput): # pass date as widget to DateForm
    input_type = 'date'

class DateForm(forms.Form):
    # CHANGE DATEINPUT TO DATEFORM
    start_time = forms.DateTimeField(widget=DateInput)
    end_time = forms.DateTimeField(widget=DateInput)

    def process(self):
        cleaned = self.cleaned_data
```

**html file**

```
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<div class="date">
    <br>
    <h3>Select to view distance and orders by timeframe</h3>
    <form name="date-input" method="POST" action="/date-input/">
        <label for="start">Start date:</label>
        <input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start" value="2018-12-01" min="2018-12-01" max="2019-06-30">

        <label for="end">End date:</label>
        <input type="date" id="end" name="trip-end" value="2018-12-01" min="2018-12-01" max="2019-07-01">

        <br>
        <br>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock content %}

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script>

var start_date = $("#start").val(); // const can't be re-assigned or redeclared
var end_date = $("#end").val();  

    function ajaxRequest (){
        var start_date = $("#start").val();
        var end_date = $("#end").val();
        $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
            type: "POST",
            url: '/date-input/', // calls data from /date-input/ endpoint
            data: {
                'start_date': start_date,       // add the order id to the POST parameters
                'end_date': end_date,
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': "{{csrf_token}}",
            },
            success: function (data) {   // `data` is from `homepage` view function
                console.log("this block of code isn't useless!!")
                console.log(data.start_date)
                console.log(data.end_date)
            },
            error: function (data, xhr, status, error) {
                console.log("yikes")
            }
        });
    }
   
    $("#start, #end").change(function() { // calling select id
        start_date = $("#start").val();
        end_date = $("#end").val();  // get the selected subject ID from the HTML dropdown list 
        
        if (start_date < end_date) {
            ajaxRequest();
        } 
    });
        

</script>
```

Comment: Your form has the fields `start_time` and `end_time` rather than `start_date` and `end_date`.

Comment: thanks - my form validates! but the start/end times still don't append to my form - this is what i get when i print form. any ideas? `<tr><th><label for="id_start_date">Start date:</label></th><td><input id="id_start_date" name="start_date" type="date" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_end_date">End date:</label></th><td><input id="id_end_date" name="end_date" type="date" /></td></tr>`

Comment: In your HTML file the form controls are named `trip-start` and `trip-end` instead of `start_date` and `end_date`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because my reputation isn't enough, but if you mean it is showing the html instead of the form, try putting {% autoescapeoff %} on top of your html, and {% endautoescape %} on bottom.

Also, it looks like just using '{% csrf_token %}' in your form might clean your code up a bit.